# Show that If $A$ is Noetherian, then $A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a faithfully flat $A$-algebra.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian, flatness

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Show that if $A$ is Noetherian, then $A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a faithfully flat $A$-algebra.

I've already shown that $A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a flat $A$-algebra (by showing that $A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a flat $A[x_1,...,x_n]$-algebra and $A[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a flat $A$-algebra). How can I take this further to show that $A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ is a faithfully flat $A$-algebra?

A separate exercise (shown below) that I've completed provides different equivalent conditions for a flat $R$-algebra $S$ to be faithfully flat, where $R$ and $S$ are commutative rings. Could I use one of these conditions?

Let $S$ be a flat $R$-algebra. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

i) $a^{ec} = a$ for all ideals $a$ of $R$.

ii) $\text{Spec}(S) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(R)$ is surjective.

iii) For every maximal ideal $m$ of $R$ we have $m^e \neq (1)$.

iv) If $M$ is any non-zero $R$-module, then $M_S \neq 0$.

v) For every $R$-module $M$, the mapping $x \mapsto 1 \otimes x$ of $R$ into $M_S$ is injective.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Pick one of them and try using it.  I would recommend (iii) or (iv) probably.

Comment: Use ii). It is almost trivial (or at least very easy) to show the map is surjective.

Comment: @lhl73 would that require me to show that $Spec(A[[x_1,...,x_n]]) \rightarrow Spec(A[x_1,...,x_n])$ is surjective and $Spec(A[x_1,...,x_n]) \rightarrow Spec(A)$ is surjective, hence the composite is surjective?

Comment: Having given this a bit more thought I must apologize for my comment: I'm not so sure I know how to do this. I thought it trivial because I thought one could construct a right-inverse by associating to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ the ideal generated by $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$. (This works for the polynomial ring) But upon reflection it is not clear to me that the ideal thus constructed is a prime ideal.

Comment: @lhl73 Would using i) be easier here? That wouldn't require any discussion of prime ideals.

Comment: @lhl73 Would it be accurate to say that, if $a$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $a^e = a + a \cdot (x_1,...,x_n)$, and that, then, $a^{ec} = a$? That seems straightforward to argue, but I'm not seeing it yet. Perhaps I haven't studied the flat ring homomorphism $f:A \rightarrow A[[x_1,...,x_n]]$ enough yet.

Comment: @lhl73 Just use the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]] \in \operatorname{Spec}(A[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]])$ consisting of all formal power series with coefficients in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @michiganbiker898 Using (i) is fine too.  If $I$ is an ideal of $A$, then the extension $I^e$ consists, by definition, of all the elements of $A[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$ of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i F_i$ with $a_i \in I$ and $F_i \in A[[x_1, \ldots, x_n]]$.  Note that all of these elements have coefficients in $I$.  So an element of $I^{ec}$ is simultaneously an element of $A$ and a power series with coefficients in $I$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan I see. Thanks! Is there anything else needed to show that $I^{ec} = I$?

Comment: @michiganbiker898 well, the argument I gave above shows that in this case $I^{ec} \subseteq I$. You should also check that for any ring extension $A \subseteq B$ and ideal $I$ of $A$, we have $I \subseteq I^{ec}$.